# Is this a valid way to avoid repetition?

Tags: vocabulary

I want to avoid the repetition of *working* in this phrase:

> I feel great working with this technology, and working on challenging projects.

Is the following correct?

> I feel great working with this technology, as well on challenging projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**as well as on**  is the phrase you want.

But the sentence would be better if you reversed the order of the clauses, putting the more general idea first.

I enjoy working on challenging projects, and it is great to work with this technology.

I changed "feel great" to "enjoy" because "I feel great" and, to a lesser extent, the one I suggested, "it is great to....", are informal, and your context suggested a letter to a business. One would not expect to find "I feel great" in a letter responding to an open job position, but that could be a generational thing. I could be a dinosaur.

Comment: I agree that "I feel great working with" is not the tone I would generally use on a resume or such. On the other hand, if I was hiring someone, I can't imagine that I'd reject an applicant for using such informal phrases.

Comment: It would depend on the job. If the job entailed frequent communication with managers and persons of influence within a large organization, it would be important to understand "tone of voice" when writing, and I might reject the applicant. If it was for a junior programming position in a department where open pizza boxes and half-finished cans of Jolt Cola on the conference room table were a frequent sight, it would not faze me in the least :-)

Answer (score -1):

elhoucine,
Apart from the sentence construction, you should not use a comma before 'and' nor 'as'.
The comma implies a pause but the 'and' and 'as' are already implied such, so skip the commas

Comment: You need to cite something to support this. As a native speaker of AusE, I would certainly place a comma before some _and_- and _as_-initial clauses. Pauses are a feature of spoken language, not written language.